# JUnit test for simple quadratic equation

Tags: java, junit

I know it looks primitive, but I was supposed to make a java program to calculate quadratic equation's roots and make it as simple (i.e. readable) as possible and write a test for it.

Obviously I already got the program, but I've never made a JUnit test before and I'm not sure how to begin writing it for something like this:

```
if(a != 0) { 
    if(delta > 0) { 
        x1 = ((-b)-deltas)/(2*a);
        x2 = ((-b)+deltas)/(2*a);
        System.out.println("x1=" + x1 + "\n" + "x2=" + x2);
    } else if(delta == 0) { 
        x1 = (-b)/(2*a);
        System.out.println("x1=" + x1);
    } else { 
        System.out.println("No real roots.");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Error: division by zero.");
}
```

Deltas is obviously delta's square root.

I was told that the test should contain examples for all the cases (4), but everything I found so far requires creation of additional classes etc.

I don't even know if I should use try catch, or something else?

Comment: You may take a look at [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JUnit:

Given class:

```
public class Compute {

    static double[] solve(double a, double b, double delta) {

        double x1, x2;
        double[] results = new double[2];

        if (a != 0) {
            if (delta > 0) {
                x1 = ((-b) - delta) / (2 * a);
                x2 = ((-b) + delta) / (2 * a);
                results[0] = x1;
                results[1] = x2;
                System.out.println("x1=" + x1 + "\n" + "x2=" + x2);
            } else if (delta == 0) {
                x1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
                System.out.println("x1=" + x1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No real roots.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: division by zero.");
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Its test should look something like (e.g. a=1, b=-3, delata = 5):

```
public class ComputeTest {

...
    /**
     * Test of solve method, of class Compute.
     */
    @Test
    public void testSolve() {
        double a = 1;
        double b = -3;
        double delta = 5;
        double[] expectedResult = {-1,4}; // x1 and x2
        double[] result = Compute.solve(a, b, delta);

        assertArrayEquals(expectedResult, result); // make the actual test

        fail("The test case is a prototype."); // fail otherwise
    }

}
```

Pay attention that `assertArrayEquals`  for  `double[]` has been added in JUnit 4.6. 
More information is [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/index.html) .

Comment: It would actually be better to use `assertArrayEquals(String message, double[] expecteds, double[] actuals, double delta)` and passing a reasonable value for `delta`. Doubles are not perfectly precise, and the expected result in your test might differ slightly from what your code does (even though both are "correct")

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a function. e.g. `int[] rootsOfQuadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c)` or something similar. Return roots and remove all `System.out.println`. You may print result in your client function.
2. Implement a [parameterized test](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests). Each test data element should contain `a`, `b`, `c`, and `expectedResults`.
3. Run your test.

You may consider to use [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) next time.